# I am trying to attach the <img id="draggable"> to $( "#draggable" ).draggable(); and it's not working. how can i connect them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am trying to attach the img id="draggable" that i'm creating within the js file to $( "#draggable" ).draggable(); and it's not working. how can i connect them?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "***",
    success: function(response){
        $.each(response, function(key, users){
            $.each(users, function(key, user){

            $('#users').append(
                        '<div class="col ui-widget-content"><b>id:</b>' + user.id + '&nbsp <b>name:</b>' + user.name + '<img id="draggable" class="emoji" src="' + user.picture + '" alt="user photo" width="100px"></div>'             
                       );   

            });
        });
    }
});  

$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
```

Comment: Please read [ask], edit your title to be a title, and put some effort into explaining what the issue is in the question.

Comment: If you have multiple users, there will be multiple elements with id="draggable", you should use <img class="draggable emoji" ... instead and: $( ".draggable" ).draggable();

Comment: it is true and it's a good point, but it will work only if the images are created in the HTML file.. still not working... as I understand it I have a problem on when the images are created in the js file, seems like after the $( "#draggable" ).draggable() is created and thats why they are disconnected..

Comment: You need to provide the value of response (or the data structure), I don't understand why you iterate over response to get an "users" variable... does that mean that response is an array of arrays or users? It looks weird.

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks, I found that I just needed to add the instance of $('.draggable').draggable(); into the $.each loop.
and yes its an array of array.
:)

Comment: I think it should be enough to execute it at the end of the success function [ success: function(response){ ... $('.draggable').draggable(); } ]